# Get values from array inside another array for later storing them in db

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, codeigniter-3

I'm sending 2 datas with same name at the front side like this

```
   <h1>First Address</h1>
<input name="address[1][street]" value="Hauptstr" />
<input name="address[1][city]" value="Berlin"  />

<h2>Second Address</h2>
<input name="address[2][street]" value="Wallstreet" />
<input name="address[2][city]" value="New York" />
```

And then I'm trying to store that value in my database through my model methods in codeigniter 3

This is what I was doing before with just 1 data

```
    $streetinfo['street'] = $this->input->post('street');
    $streetinfo['city'] = $this->input->post('city');
    $newAddress= json_encode($streetinfo);

   $entry = array(
        "id" => "1",
        "address" => $newAddress,
    );
    $result= $this->address->insert_entry($entry);
```

But now that im dealing with more input data i dont know how to handle it
im storing the data like this now

```
$streetinfo = $this->input->post('street');
```

and when i do the var_dump for $streetinfo i get this

```
array(2) { [1]=> array(2) { ["street"]=> string(1) "1" ["city"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(2) { ["street"]=> string(1) "3" ["city"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

}

And then now, I don't know how to get each value from those keys and make each insert in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're now passing the data as an array, you're supposed to use indexes to access each variable. First, store the input data in a variable, then access the different indexes and their respective keys/values.

```
$data = $this->input->post('address');
$street1 = $data[1]['street'];
$city1   = $data[1]['city'];

$street2 = $data[2]['street'];
$city2   = $data[2]['city'];
```

If you then want to save them to the database, make sure you have the required fields/columns in your database and continue saving the data as usual.

Is this what you're looking for?